# Sequelize - Cannot read property 'define' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to insert a record into MYSQL table using sequelize.

Installed sequelize and mysql.

```
npm install --save sequelize

npm install --save mysql
```

defined it in app.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
```

db.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('randomdb', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port : 8889,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    }
});

exports.sequelize = sequelize;
module.exports = Sequelize;
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sequelize = require('../db').sequelize;

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Express'});
});

router.get('/adduser', function (req, res) {
    var User = sequelize.define('users', {
        first_name: Sequelize.STRING
    });

    sequelize.sync().then(function () {
        return User.create({
            first_name: 'janedoe'
        });
    }).then(function (jane) {
        console.log(jane.get({
            plain: true
        }))
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's the error.

> Cannot read property 'define' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined

What's missing?

**EDIT 2**

db.js

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('randomdb', 'root', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: 8889,

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        idle: 10000
    },
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
});

var db = {};

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

models/user.js

```
var db = require('../db'),
    sequelize = db.sequelize,
    Sequelize = db.Sequelize;

var User = sequelize.define('random', {
    first_name: Sequelize.STRING
});

module.exports = User;
```

routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../db'),
    sequelize = db.sequelize,
    Sequelize = db.Sequelize;

var User = require('../models/user');

router.get('/adduseryes', function (req, res) {
    sequelize.sync().then(function () {
        return User.create({
            first_name: 'janedoe'
        });
    }).then(function (jane) {
        res.send("YES");
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Try alter for tiny: `first_name: Sequelize.STRING` to `first_name: sequelize.STRING`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your db.js file, you are overwriting the `exports` variable with the Sequelize var.  In node.js, `module.exports` == `exports`.  Try this instead:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize(...);

var db = {};

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Then, you can modify your import in the routes/index.js to be as follows:

```
var db = require('../db'),
  sequelize = db.sequelize,
  Sequelize = db.Sequelize;
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Could you please check EDIT2? I made a few changes, right now it works but I wonder something. In `user.js`, I put `module.exports = User;` , then used this in `index.js`as `var User = require('../models/user');` Is my `User` variable in the `index.js` looks for other one? Is that how it works?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but if you are confused about what each variable is, you could always just print them out with `console.log`.  Also, you may want to examine your new code because the callback of creating the user might not get called correctly.

Comment: Okay, let's put it that way. We "throw" db in the db.js using module.exports and "catch" in the routes/index.js as db with require, is that right? Hope it's clear now :) Thank you again.

Comment: The naming of the variables is arbitrary and you could name it whatever when you import it with `require`.  You could say `var abcd = require('../db'),` `sequelize = abcd.sequelize,` `Sequelize = abcd.Sequelize`.

Comment: i faced the same issue, probably there could be the  typo error. example Users.create({foo: 1}). check users is correct.